# Three.js detect click on an object with Raycaster don't work

Tags: angular, three.js

I tried to detect a click on a Three.js object with a raycaster but not any collision is detected.
I use Angular an here is my code :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-viewer-3d',
  templateUrl: './viewer3d.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./viewer3d.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class Viewer3dComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  pickPosition = {x: 0, y: 0};
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  pickedObject;
  raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

  ngDoCheck() {
    this.cameraState.emit(JSON.stringify(this.camera.matrix.toArray()));
    console.log(this.pickPosition);
    this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.pickPosition, this.camera);
    const intersectedObjects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children);
    if (intersectedObjects.length) {
      if (this.pickedObject !== intersectedObjects[0].object) {
        // console.log(this.pickedObject);
        this.pickedObject = intersectedObjects[0].object;
      }
      console.log(this.pickedObject);
    } else {
      this.pickedObject = null;
      console.log('NULL');
    }
  }

  @HostListener('window:mouseout')
  @HostListener('window:mouseleave')
  clearPickPosition() {
    this.pickPosition.x = -100000;
    this.pickPosition.y = -100000;
    // console.log(this.pickPosition);
  }

  @HostListener('window:mousemove', ['$event'])
  setPickPosition(event) {
    const pos = this.getCanvasRelativePosition(event);
    this.pickPosition.x = (pos.x / this.canvas.width) * 2 - 1;
    this.pickPosition.y = (pos.y / this.canvas.height) * -2 + 1;  // note we flip Y
    // console.log(this.pickPosition);
  }

  getCanvasRelativePosition(event) {
    const rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: (event.clientX - rect.left) * this.canvas.width / rect.width,
      y: (event.clientY - rect.top) * this.canvas.height / rect.height,
    };
  }
}
```

In my console, when I move my mouse, y and x go between -1 and 1 but it print always NULL. So, intersectedObjects.length  = 0.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank's in advance

Comment: Maybe the recursive flag?: `raycaster.intersectObjects( this.scene.children, true );`

Comment: Yes ! Thank’s a lot ! Can you make an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: That's OK, go ahead and answer your own question, or delete the question. This has been answered many times before.

Answer (score 0):

```
raycaster.intersectObjects( this.scene.children, true );
```